# php - count elements of array

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to know in the end how much success and failed i have. I wanted to use the array function but i don't know how to continue from here:

```
public function array_internal($the_string)
$pass=  Array();
$failed = Array();
  if(strstr($the_string,"Success"))
    {
        $pass[] = +1;
    }
  else
    {
        $failed[] = +1;
    }

count($pass);
```

This step is running every assert function like this:

```
 try {
      $this->assertEquals("off", $this->getValue("page"));
      throw new PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError("Success");
    } catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
      $this->array_internal($e->toString());
    }
```

The function itself is ok. my problem is only with the counter.

Thank you!

**Edit**
I tried to do something like this:

```
$pass= 0;
$failed = 0;
public function array_internal($the_string)

  if(strstr($the_string,"Success"))
    {
        $pass += 1;
    }
  else
    {
        $failed += 1;
    }

$pass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the array except counting, so why not just use an integer?

```
$pass= 0;
$failed = 0;


public function array_internal($the_string)

  global $pass, $failed;

  if(strstr($the_string,"Success"))
    {
        $pass += 1;
    }
  else
    {
        $failed += 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that `array_internal` is called multiple times, as there is no loop in the function. Global variables would be better. -- I see you've updated your answer ;)

Comment: @Harmen yes I took the initialization out, but the original question was also resetting it each time.  I agree they should be global or handled some other way.

Comment: can you please explain to me how to do then global vars? (and yes,`array_internal` is called multiple times)

Comment: @Ronny when you declare a variable outside of a function, you need to put `global $pass;` inside the function in order to access it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use global variables as `$pass` and `$fail`, which you can increment by `$pass++` and `$fail++`?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function array_internal($the_string)
$pass=0;
$failed=0;
if (strstr($the_string,"Success"))
{
    $pass += 1;
}
else
{
    $failed += 1;
}
```

Comment: @ronny: then you have error in this `if(strstr($the_string,"Success"))
`

Answer (score 1):

`$pass[] = +1` creates a new key value pair in the `$pass` array, and adds `1` to the new value. This is probably not what you want to do. See other answers for what you do want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pass=  Array();
$failed = Array();
```

Creates new array instances. The return value of your function `array_internal` will always be 0 or 1. You also never use `$failed`.

A much simpler function would be:

```
public function array_internal( $the_string )
  $pass = 0; 
  if( strstr( $the_string, "Success" ) )
  {            
      $pass = 1;
  }
  return $pass;
}
```

Like Harmen said, you need to use an external int counter. Unlike Harmen, I would try not to use a global variable if possible, but a class variable to limit it's scope.

Maybe a static variable of a class, `TestClass`, called `$passes` like:

```
TestClass::$passes += $this->array_internal($e->toString());
```